# Is this mold on my OSB subfloor?

Tags: mold, plywood, osb

I wanted to get the opinion of the community here with this issue I'm having.

New construction home here, pics are from the basement of the underside of the main floor subfloor. My builder is saying its paint splatter from the OSB manufacturing process (which I'm fully aware of) and that it can't be mold because he uses a mold and mildew resistant OSB.

Can anyone confirm or deny my suspicion here of these black spots being black mold and not paint splatter?

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]

Comment: Take a paper towel and dampen with some bleach.  Rub the spots and the ink/paint label on the OSB.  Mold should rub off easy, paint/ink should not change.

Comment: Get a clear picture of the labeling on the OSB to ensure that it is, indeed, mold resistant. That should be labeled and would be cause for an upcharge on supplies. TBH, I've never seen such a thing marketed at my local big box store, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Also, I don't recall seeing that much splatter everywhere on plywood or OSB. Don't recall seeing much splatter _at all_ from the labeling process.

Comment: Think you need a big dog for that much splatter.   About 3:30 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCvuIaxeLKE

Comment: It's not mold. Notice how the spots are the same color as all the stamps? Yeah. With that much mold you'd _smell_ it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the black spots on my basement ceiling?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170989/what-are-the-black-spots-on-my-basement-ceiling)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the black spots on my basement ceiling?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170989/what-are-the-black-spots-on-my-basement-ceiling)

Comment: To be sure, call the manufacturer, then send a picture, they'll quickly confirm if it's typical ink splatter.